# Python + Django ImportError: cannot import name signals from Python2.5 to Python2.7

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have django-registration installed. I just updated my Python installation from 2.5 to 2.7.

Everything works okay but when I try to run my Django app, I get the error below.

```
C:\django\pley>python manage.py runserver
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x02FA6830>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 249,
 in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 28, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 146, in
 get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 64, in
_populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 78, in
load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\django\pley\..\pley\accounts\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from registration import signals
ImportError: cannot import name signals
```

If you need more details, like the code for the other files, just comment on this question so that I can update.

Comment: I was not able to fix this. I went around the problem by using Cygwin's python installation instead. [Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to answer this myself. Thanks to bahamas from #django freenode.

First go to your Python shell

```
>>> import registration
>>> print registration.__file__
/home/wenbert/.local/lib/python/registration/__init__.pyc
```

Do a:

```
$ ls -la /home/wenbert/.local/lib/python/registration
```

I did not find `signals.py` in the directory.

So, download the tar.gz file from: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src and reinstall.

**TL;DR**
I had a broken a installation (no signals.py) of django-registration. Download from source and reinstall manually.

Answer (score 1):

Seems ok to me. When you unpack [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) you get 2 folders `doc` and `registration`. In `registration` folder you have a file called `signals.py`. This is precisely the file that your django app is trying to import.

Either see if you have added `django-registration` as INSTALLED_APPS in your project settings.py.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have it installed. It was working in my Python2.5 installation but now it is not. I have tried both 2.6 and 2.7 and still won't work.